# Redux initial state from API issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

My issue is that I want to fetch all products from the database and set them into the Redux initial state, to do this I did an action `SET_PRODUCTS_LIST` and in the action. payload I simply passed the products fetched in the component (I am using next js), all works fine but when I try to fire another action like `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART` the products in the initial state are gone which it results impossible to add more than 1 product to the cart.

Inside my component:

```
function Header({ cartProps, setProducts }) {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const products = await getProducts();
    setProducts(products);
  }, []);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cartProps: state.cartState,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setProducts,
})(Header);
```

the action to set products:

```
import { SET_PRODUCTS_LIST } from "./types";

export const setProducts = (products) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_PRODUCTS_LIST,
      payload: products,
    });
  };
};
```

My cart reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  itemNumbers: 0,
  cartCost: 0,
  products: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PRODUCTS_LIST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
      };
    }

    case ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART: {
      //let addQuantity = {
      // ...state.products.filter((p) => p.productName === action.paylaod),
      //   };
      console.log(state.products);
      return {
        itemNumbers: state.itemNumbers + 1,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

maybe I am completely doing wrong the logic about fetching the products in order to have them in the initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const initialState = {
  itemNumbers: 0,
  cartCost: 0,
  products: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PRODUCTS_LIST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
      };
    }

    case ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART: {
      //let addQuantity = {
      // ...state.products.filter((p) => p.productName === action.paylaod),
      //   };
      console.log(state.products);
      return {
        ...state
        itemNumbers: state.itemNumbers + 1,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

You should always return `state` but in `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART` case you return only

```
{
  itemNumbers: state.itemNumbers + 1,
}
```

so you need to add `...state` before `itemNumbers: state.itemNumbers + 1,`